# FileResult DownloadFile method deletes Database entry on return

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am working on a receipt/invoice app and have my .pdf files uploaded and converted to byte then stored on a database as a varbinary(MAX), I just noticed that once I download the .pdf the varbinary column in my table is left as NULL.

I can't see anything obvious or that looks like it would relate to the issue but I am by no means an expert. Excuse my poor SqlConnection just thrown in, I am working on that next but I find it so difficult to do what I want with the constraints of Entity Framework and the structure.

````
@Html.ActionLink("Download", "DownloadFile", new { id = item.Id })</td> ```
````

```
    [HttpGet]
    public FileResult DownloadFile(int id)
    {
        List<Reg> ObjFiles = GetFileList();

        var FileById = (from FC in ObjFiles
                        where FC.Id.Equals(id)
                        select new { FC.FileName, FC.FileContent }).ToList().FirstOrDefault();

        return File(FileById.FileContent, "application/pdf", FileById.FileName);
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public PartialViewResult FileDetails()
    {
        List<Reg> DetList = GetFileList();

        return PartialView("Reg", DetList);
    }

    private List<Reg> GetFileList()
    {
        List<Reg> DetList = new List<Reg>();

        string connectString = @"server=*placeholder*;Initial Catalog=*placeholder*;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;";
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectString);
        //DbConnection();
        con.Open();
        DetList = SqlMapper.Query<Reg>(con, "FileDetails", commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure).ToList();
        con.Close();
        Debug.WriteLine(DetList);
        return DetList;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

An error on my end, I was deleting the column data by other means.

Feel free to use this as an example for .pdf to binary on a db.